# Scala Swing - button with action

Tags: swing, scala, button, icons, action

I've created a button with title and icon in my view.

```
object playButton extends Button("play") {
  icon = new ImageIcon(getClass.getResource("/Play.gif"))
  verticalTextPosition = Alignment.Bottom
  horizontalTextPosition = Alignment.Center
}
```

Now I want to add it some action in the controller.

```
view.playButton.action = Action(view.playButton.text) { 
  //...
}
```

The problem is, that this action overrides buttons icon. So... i tried:

```
view.playButton.action = Action(view.playButton.text) { 
  icon = view.playButton.icon
}
```

Compiler says:

```
[info] Compiling main sources...
[error] .../Controller.scala:11: not found: value icon
[error]     icon = view.playButton.icon
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
```

What am I doing wrong? Action in documentation has this setter for icon field: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/Action.html.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [source for scala.swing.Action](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_1/src//swing/scala/swing/Action.scala#L1)

In the companion `object`:

```
def apply(title: String)(body: =>Unit) = new Action(title) { 
  def apply() { body }
}
```

In other words, as a convenience to you, they take the block (where you put `icon = ...`) and make that be the event handler for the Action.

What you actually want to do is subclass:

```
new Action("Hello") {
    icon = ...

    def apply() = ...
}
```

This does not appear to be documented.